# What is this dot notation in android?

Tags: java, android, syntax, builder

Could someone explain the dot notation used below. Is that a single or several statements or shorthand for something else?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setTitle("ALERTTILESTRING")
        .setMessage("alertNameString")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setNegativeButton("Close",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

Comment: It's just chaining methods. [Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining#Java)

Comment: Meaning it's a single statement split over multiple lines. It's for readability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a shorthand for all the methods called on the AlertBuilder object builder. It's the same as:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
builder.setTitle("ALERTTILESTRING");
builder.setMessage("alertNameString");
builder.setCancelable(false);
builder.setNegativeButton("Close",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 4):

That's the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) implemented in Java.  All that's happening here is that the builder object of type AlertDialog.Builder is being returned from each method called on it, so you can chain the calls together in sequence.  In your example, it's no different if you just called the same methods repeatedly on the `builder` instance.  But that would be more typing.